# Allowing anonymous users to contact node authors

Tags: webforms, message-subscribe, 8

I want anonymous users to send messages to node authors. Also I want the sent messages to be visible to node authors in their user account. Here is what I have tried so far:

- Private message - Solves what I am looking for but does not work for anonymous users
- Webforms - New to it but I don't see a way for node authors to access the sent messages within their account

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this can be done by combining the core Contact module with the [Contact Storage](https://www.drupal.org/project/contact_storage) module.

Steps to implement

1. Enable the Contact module and give anonymous the permission **Use users' personal contact forms**.
2. Enable the Contact Storage module and create a view showing **Contact message**. Configure a contextual filter with the user ID so that only messages to the logged-in user are displayed.